# Where I want write jquery?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

i am new to SharePoint, and i am using SharePoint 2013, here i am trying to implement the two level cascading drop downs. so till now i have loaded spservice.js and jquery library through the master page. here my problem is i don't know where i want to write spservice script. before that i followed this link http://www.bentedder.com/sharepoint-sketches-spservices-cascading-dropdowns/
i am using sharepoint designer 2013... from that link he said to write he script inside the PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead content place holder, but it is not editable and i tried the following way its too not working

```
<asp:content ContentPlaceHolderID="aaaa" runat="server">
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "States",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Country",
        childColumn: "State",
        debug: true
    })
})
</script>
</asp:content>
        </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
      </td>
```

but its show the error message like Web Part Error: Unknown server tag. Correlation ID: f674859c-4cb4-60ab-2e10-2d42828b0ea5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Edit the page in **Advanced Mode**. Edit the page in SP Designer  and in the ribbon you can Advanced Mode option. Then Add your script in **PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead**.